# In our library, how to tell webpack to skip dependencies?

Tags: node.js, webpack, officedev

We have a library that is traditionally client-side only.  It uses HTTP Request (or several other dependency libraries) to make REST calls.  When using the library, user will initialize with a particular request provider and off they go.

We use webpack in our examples to utilize our library.

It is now extended it to use node-fetch, so if someone wants to use it from nodejs that's supported too.

For people using webpack, webpack is now attempting to pack node-fetch and the require call is failing in the browser.  We can get around this with setting an external

```
"externals" : {
    "node-fetch": "{}"
}
```

Is there a way to define our library so that if the consumer is using webpack target: web, it'd skip the require check for node-fetch?  And similarly, if the consumer is using webpack target: nodejs - it needs to include the node-fetch component.

The project in question is https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-JS-Core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. So according to [This commit and conversation linked to it](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/commit/efb2dd483f4d360cd19ed222688316624b8e0f35), the automatic module resolution field (also known as a `described-resolve` to the webpack resolver instance) changes based on what your target is.

By default, when target is `node` in your webpack build, resolution in package.json field will default to the `main` field else, `browser` field takes priority by default.

More reference https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/151

Comment: Our package.json update PR was fixed and issue closed.  Thanks :)

I leave this comment here as an example of what it should look like.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-JS-Core/blob/master/package.json 

and here is the link to the 'spec' https://github.com/defunctzombie/package-browser-field-spec

Answer (score 1):

The links provided in the accepted answer & comment show how to do this, so +1 to those, but just to surface it directly here

> Is there a way to define our library so that if the consumer is using webpack target: web, it'd skip the require check for node-fetch

**Yes**. In the library's `package.json`, add a `browser` field with the following

```
"browser": {
  "node-fetch": false
}
```

This provides a hint to webpack and other bundlers that the the `node-fetch` module should be ignored - i.e. do not even attempt to include it in the bundle - when the target is `web`. When the target is `node`, it will be included.

---

Note that the above relies on the code in the client bundle **never** using `node-fetch`. In that sense it can be considered unsafe, because there is no compile-time guarantee of this, and if it happens, it will just error and probably crash your client. If you're **absolutely sure** it can never be used client-side, though, this *is* the simplest way to get this done.

For more safety - i.e. if you want the client code to only warn if you try to use `node-fetch` - you also have the option of providing a shim to the module that the client bundle can include instead, and for instance just log a warning in the shim implementation if it gets used. You do this in the same way, just by providing a path to the shim module instead of `false`

```
"browser": {
  "node-fetch": "./shims/node-fetch.js"
}
```